# Jetpack compose with Google Place API

Tags: google-places-api, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use Place SDK with jetpack compose but I can not find any resource on how to implement this.

```
@Composable
fun PlaceSearchView() {
    // Initialize the SDK
    Places.initialize(applicationContext, "apiKey")

    
    val placesClient = Places.createClient(this)
}
```

The above code is based on what is available in the Documentation and I am getting the error

> Unresolved reference: applicationContext

My question now: is there a dedicated approach to using google place API in Jetpack Compose?

> 'this' is not defined in this context

Comment: Assuming you've subclassed the `Application` class, you may use `LocalContext.current as Application` from within a composable to get a handle of the Application class, which can be used as a context. But I'm sure you definitely don't want to do this. Your composables shouldn't know how to initialize the places SDK. Your previews will most likely break with your current approach.

Comment: @Rafsanjani so what do you suggest? or if you did something in that line before.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Places client? Perhaps I can give you a sample code @King

Comment: I actually want to create my own Place search custom UI and I am working with Compose @Rafsanjani

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to create an intent to launch autocomplete widget as an intent.  The code is similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#create_an_autocomplete_intent)

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myUseCase: MyUseCase, @ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context): ViewModel() {
    init {
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, "insert api key")
    }

    val field = listOf(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)

    }
```

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(myViewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, exploreViewModel.field).build(context)

    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
       
        if(it.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it.data    
            latLng = place.latLng
            Log.d("place LatLng: ", latLng.toString())
             
            // move the camera position of the map

          // cameraPositionState.move(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lonLat, 15f))
        }

    }
     FloatingActionButton(modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopStart)
            .padding(10.dp),
            onClick = {
                launcher.launch(intent)
            }) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = 
      "")
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir I am trying this code to use autocomplete place in a project but it is giving me error in this line "latLng = place.latLng" android studio cant recognize latLng and place.latLng please share full code to solve this error. Thank you

Comment: @heetkanabar A 'val' is missing before latLng and a ')' is missing right after it.data

Comment: Hello @Lena I tried your code and I successfully launched it but the problem is after writing one latter the autocomplete closes and some time app is crashes do you have any solution about this? error :- "Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't." please look at this tell me what you think.

Comment: @heetkanabar Are you sure it.data is returning a valid value?

Comment: @Lena yah it is not returning place it should be and here is the full error :- Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=988884199, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.trip/com.example.trip.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't.  and in this error you can see that the result code is 2 but it should be 0 as per your code

Comment: well btw I asked this question over here you can check this out for more info here is the link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983249/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-intent-expected-to-contain-a-place-but-does hope you will find it helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can always integrate fragments into Jetpack Compose.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/address_auto_complete_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.DeliveryAppDemo.FullscreenContainer"
    tools:context=".composable.AddressAutoCompleteFragment">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteFragmentScreen() {
    Log.i(TAG, "AutoCompleteFragmentScreen context: ${LocalContext.current}")
    val activity = LocalContext.current as? MainActivity ?: return

    Log.i(TAG, "AutoCompleteFragmentScreen has activity: $activity")

    AndroidViewBinding(FragmentAddressAutoCompleteBinding::inflate) {

        val autoCompleteFragment =
            activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?

        autoCompleteFragment?.setPlaceFields(listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autoCompleteFragment?.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
            override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
            }

            override fun onError(status: Status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: $status")
            }
        })
    }
}
```