# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't. in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to make a app that can search the places with google autocomplete search in jetpack compose but when I launch the intent of the autocomplete and after writing one later app is crashing here is my code:-

**My ViewModel**

```
init {
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(context, "$API_KEY", Locale.US);
    }
}
val field = listOf(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
```

**My UI**

```
val context = LocalContext.current
        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, viewModel.field).build(context)

        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {

            if(it.resultCode == 2){
                val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it.data)
                        val latLng = place.latLng
                        Log.d("place LatLng: ", latLng.toString())

                // move the camera position of the map

                // cameraPositionState.move(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lonLat, 15f))
            }

        }
```

**My Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                Process: com.example.trip, PID: 19245
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=988884199, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.trip/com.example.trip.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't.
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5015)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent expected to contain a Place, but doesn't.
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzha.zze(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.6.0:1)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzfo.zzb(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.6.0:3)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.6.0:1)
                                                                                                    at com.example.trip.ui.theme.tripSection.createTrip.CreateTripScreenKt$CreateTripScreen$2$1$launcher$1.invoke(CreateTripScreen.kt:116)
                                                                                                    at com.example.trip.ui.theme.tripSection.createTrip.CreateTripScreenKt$CreateTripScreen$2$1$launcher$1.invoke(CreateTripScreen.kt:113)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.compose.ActivityResultRegistryKt$rememberLauncherForActivityResult$1$1.onActivityResult(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:105)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:392)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:351)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:638)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**My gradle**

```
//Google places api
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'
```

Comment: You should replace "$API_KEY" by API_KEY (I suppose API_KEY is a local variable in your ViewModel).
Also what happen if you replace ```it.resultCode == 2``` by ```it.resultCode == RESULT_OK```

Comment: @Lena there is my api key over there but I just changed it here and by replacing 2 with RESULT_OK is the same problem the window of autocomplete is crashing 

Comment: @Lena well if know any repository of place picker with jetpack please tell me that would be great help btw Thank you for till now 

Comment: I had the same issue so I have implemented my own place picker. You can take a look at my project https://github.com/morganesoula/catlife/tree/autocomplete_places (branch autocomplete_places)

Comment: @Lena Thank you for your code I think that would help me